# Returning special ASCII characters in Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-web-api

I have a web api action method which returns an object.

Some of the properties in this object contain ASCII characters, specifically the bullet (ASCII character - 149  •)

When I call this api action all the bullet characters get replaced with â€¢

Is there anyway I can change my api action to keep the bullets encoded as is?

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<Candidate> Get(int id)
{    
    var manager = new CandidateManager(Country);
    Candidate candidate = await Task.FromResult(manager.Find(id));
    return candidate;
}
```

Comment: What are you using to do the http request? I think it should work if you add `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8` to the request header

Comment: @ShamPooSham works, thank you!Please add as the answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to your HTTP request header:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```